# how to divide entities and share it in clean architecture

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, clean-architecture

For my new project in `flutter`, I am trying to follow the `Clean Architecture` and diving each different feature in `domain`, `data and` presentation`.

Now, I have initiated with the `Authentication` feature where I have started creating the `Entities` however, I am pretty much confused and stuck on how to modularize the code based on the `Clean Architecture` practice.

For example,

The response of my login service is as follow,

1. so do I need to create entities and models for all JSON nested objects like for `response` , `data` , `user` , `accountData` and `permissions` ?

   or is there any way to use `IResponse` to store common elements like `status` , `message` and `data` and then use only for relevant feature.
2. Not sure whether it is allowed to share entities in between the features. Like `user` block below can be a feature in `Authorization` and `Employee`

> ```
> {
>   "status": "success",
>   "message": "successfully login",
>   "data": {
>     "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6NywiaXNMb2dnZWRJbiI6dHJ1ZSwidGVuYW50SWQiOjEyLCJpYXQiOjE2MjU5OTE5MTAsImV4cCI6MTYyNjA3ODMxMH0.I0z9OIDnQS-MI1ya6usqycoryZ1TBwj3K52BRfrpMuY",
>     "user": {
>       "user_id": 7,
>       "email": "jd@gmail.com",
>       "first_name": "John",
>       "last_name": "Doe",
>       "phone": "",
>       "date_of_birth": "2015-08-06T00:00:00.000Z",
>       
>     },
>     "accountData": {
>       "name": "Amazon",
>       "account_id": 1
>     },
>     "permissions": [
>       "ViewAllEmployee",
>       "AddNewEmployee"
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```